# Getting text from a <pre> object with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I'm trying to get the text inside of `<pre>` tag and I have tried with `get_attribute('text')`, `get_attribute('value')`, `.text()`, `.value()`, `get_attribute("innerHTML")` but I keep failing:

Snapshot:

[image]

This is the code that i'm using:

```
import unittest
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("###")

elem=driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_admin").click()

elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[15]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input").send_keys("###")
elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[15]/div[2]/form/div[2]/input").send_keys("###")
elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[15]/div[3]/div/button[1]").click()

elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/button/span[3]').click()
time.sleep(2)
elem =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li/a')))
time.sleep(2)
elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span[1]/input[2]').send_keys('###')

time.sleep(1)

elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span[2]/button').click()

print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='output']/pre[text()]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

And this is what it says when print:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text within the `<pre>` tag you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.output > pre").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='output']/pre[contains(., 'ContactUri')]").text)
  ```

---

To extract the text ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.output > pre"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='output']/pre[contains(., 'ContactUri')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you know why it says "Loading..." and never show anything?

Comment: Check the updated xpath and let me know the status.

Comment: It keeps saying "Loading...". I have updated the question with full code and a picture of the print answer to see if you can find why isn't working, thanks!!

Comment: Checkout the updated xpath and let me know the status.